# Most efficient way to enumerate and modify over a ConcurrentBag of objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I have a ConcurrentBag of objects, and I want to do following over it:

1. enumerate all items with a where filtering.
2. for each item, check some properties, and based on the values, make some method call. After the method call, it's better to remove the item form the bag.
3. modify some properties' value and save it to the bag.

So basically I need something like following:

```
   foreach (var item in myBag.Where(it => it.Property1 = true))
        {
            
            if (item.Property2 = true)
            {
                SomeMethodToReadTheItem(item);
                //it's better to remove this item from the bag here, but 
                //there is a permeance hit, then just leave it.
            }
            else
            {
                item.Property3=  "new value";
                //now how do I save the item back to the bag?
            }
            
        }
```

Of cause it should be done in a thread-safe way. I know that the enumeration over a ConcurrentBag is actually over a "snapshot" of the real bag,  but how about with a where clause filter? Should I do a ToList to prevent it form making a new "snapshot"?
Also if you want to modify one specific item, you just bag.TryTake(out item). But since I've already get the item in the enumeration, should I "take" it again?

Any explanation/comment/sample would be very much apricated.

Thank you.

Comment: It's very unlikely that a `ConcurrentBag<T>` is the best tool for whatever you are trying to do. This class represents an unordered bag of items, and only supports taking random items one by one. You can't remove a specific item from this collection. It's a specialized collection, indented for **mixed** producer-consumer scenarios, that are extremely rare in practice.

Comment: The class is thread safe with respect to the internal consistency, however, since it contains references no guarantees are given about not shooting your self in the foot with the shared resources within.  In most cases, its conceptually easier just to use lock unless you have fairly specific use cases. Also what Theodor said

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you just create a new list and, if the WHERE filter, add it to this new list.
It would look something like this:

```
List<T> myNewList = new List<T>();
foreach (var item in myBag.Where(it => it.Property1))
    {
        if (!item.Property2)
        {
            myNewList.Add(item);
        }            
    }
```

attention to " ! "

Comment: I am not sure this adds or answers much, or is even that different than what the OP had.  Maybe you could explain why you think this is the solution

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to answer specific parts of your question without addressing the performance.

First off, the `Where` method takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as its first parameter and will itself iterate over the enumerable which will call `GetEnumerator()` once so you will only take one snapshot of the underlying `ConcurrentBag`.

Secondly the thread-safety of your code is not very clear, there may be some implicit guarantees in the rest of your code which are not specified.  For example you have a `ConcurrentBag` so your collection is thread-safe however you modify the items contained within that collection without any thread synchronisation.  If there is other code that runs the same method or in another method that reads/modifies the items in the `ConcurrentBag` concurrently then you may see data races.

Note that it is not necessary to call `TryTake` if you already have a reference to the item as it will only return the same reference.